# What exactly do this function declared into functions.php file of a WP theme?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, theme-development, customization

someone can help me to understand what exactly do this function declared into the **functions.php** file of a theme?

```
function exclude_featured_tag( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag__not_in', 'array(ID OF THE FEATURED TAG)' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_featured_tag' );
```

I am not into PHP but looking it I think that if the user is on the home page it modifya query object exluding the posts having a specific tag. Is it right?

If it's right can you explain me the last line:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_featured_tag' );
```

I think that it is used to automatically call the previous function what a specific event happen...is it right? what event? can you help me to understand how exactly work?

Tnx

Comment: Link to the source of the code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line tells WP to run this function on the `pre_get_posts` hook. That hook is the ideal place to modify the main query that will be run in order to build the page. In this case, `exclude_featured_tag()` checks whether WP is loading the home page, and whether it's about to call the main query for the page (as opposed to any other secondary queries being run). Then it modifies the query (`$query->set()`) to NOT include any post that has tag of `ID OF THE FEATURED TAG`.

For more on the `pre_get_posts` hook, see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Comment: Perfect explaination. The only last doubt is about: who say that a query is the main query?

Comment: When WP is setting up a page, there is always a main query. But there can be other, secondary queries that run. A common case is that a theme template, widget, plugin or what-have-you will call a second query via `$second_query = new WP_query( $args );` in order to cherry pick a certain set of posts for special treatment of some sort. Checking for whether you're querying the main query assures that you don't interfere with any of those other things that may be happening on the page.

Comment: Ok, perfect...now all si clear :-)